Creating and naming subfolders off of data cells in sheets
Yes another boring data entry and tracking question. This has probably been answered already on here, but I'm a super noob, so go easy one me.
I get roughly 100 shift reports daily within each report, I need pull some details to track through sheets (fines and details uploading attached files to Drive).
I've been working through the last week and realized most of this was so repetitive that theres gotta be a better way to develop it. Here's what I'm thinking:
First columns A, B, C are date, name and number ex:  A:08.19 B:John C:608. column H is "attach folder" which I've been creating with the same name: 08.19 John 608 then copy/pasta that link right in there and populating the folder with supporting evidence as well as a saved pdf of the original email report.
How can I set up my Sheet so once I finish column C, the subfolder is already createdand linked?
It's literally my third day on sheets, so I appreciate your support and kindness
cheers
I thought it would be a question of copy pasta some formula into column H but anything I type there it tries to link.
I'm working on maybe something for cell C or put a formula in an empty cell off to the right, so I'm still figuring this out, but any helpful advice would be awesome

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
